# jQuery change iteration direction

Tags: jquery, iteration

is it possible to iterate through elements from last to first one? For example from the last parent ul in a list to the nearest parent-ul one. At the moment I use each() but it would be nice to change direction...

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the `reverse()` method on `Arrays`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse

```
$($("ul li").get().reverse()).each(function(){ });
```

---

or create your own function:

```
jQuery.fn.reverse = function() {
    return this.pushStack(this.get().reverse());
};

$("ul li").reverse().each(function(){ });
```

---

**working example: http://jsfiddle.net/hunter/kdREt/**

Comment: Thank you, did not know the remove and get functions yet. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Use a for loop:

http://jsfiddle.net/ebiewener/qu9h2/

```
$(function(){
   var divs = $('div');
    for(var i=divs.length - 1; i >= 0; i--){
        console.log(divs[i]);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, the easiest way even if you are new to jQuery - I should get this one by my own :) Thanks again!

Comment: No problem. The key, obviously, is just realizing that $(...) creates an array of matched elements.